# AdminDirectory.Members.insert returns "Member already exists"

Tags: google-apps-script

I use AdminDirectory.Members.insert to automatically add new registered members to a group. sometimes, when the scripts runs on a new registration, I get "Member already exists" but when I manually add the member via the group GUI I succeed.

```js
function AddNewMember()
{
    var LastEntryMail = "john.dow@gmail.com";
    var NewMember = 
        {
         email: LastEntryMail,
         role: 'MEMBER'
        };
    var MemberExist = false;
    var pageToken, page;
    var groupEmail = 'mygroup@bmydomain';
    var groupDomainName = 'mydomain';
    
    do 
    {
      page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail,{
      domain: groupDomainName,
      orderBy: 'Email',
      maxResults: 200,
      pageToken: pageToken
      });
      var GroupMembers = page.members;
      for (var m in GroupMembers) 
      {
        var email = GroupMembers[m].email;
        if(email == LastEntryMail)     
        {
          MemberExist = true;
          break; //stop the for loop
        }
      }
      if(MemberExist == true)
      {
       break; //stop the do loop
      }
      else //new member email was not found in current page members list. go to next page
      {
       pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
      }
    } while (pageToken);
    
    if(MemberExist == false)
    {
      AdminDirectory.Members.insert(NewMember, groupEmail);
    }
  }
```

when I debug, I see that the function enter MemberExist == false, so I guess the check was positive but then it fails

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/_2BlvvbY9Sg;context-place=topicsearchin/Apps/category$3Agoogle-groups-for-business%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false). Try to check with the affected member to see if they have an alias on the affected account which may be already added. If one of their alias address has previously been added to the Group, they will not be able to be added to the Group using another alias. Contact the owner of the address and ask them if they have any alias email addresses associated with the account. If so search the group for these aliases.